# Usage of the part 'through other means'

Tags: word-order

It might not be the typical way to say this, but is it incorrect or does it sound really awkward?

> Thank you all for the birthday wishes, by postcard or through other means.

Or does it necessarily have to be:

> Thank you all for the birthday wishes, through postcards or other means.

Answer (score 1):

"By postcard or through other means" is perfectly understandable and correct, but I think "by postcard or otherwise" is more elegant and simple, without any loss of meaning.